# Is there a way to call or trigger a method for in page in another page in a windows store app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I created a settings flyout for my app where the user can select what items to display on one of the pages, but right now in order to see the changes, the user must click a refresh button on the page iteslf.

WHat I'd like to do is either have a refresh button on the settings flyout, but I'm having trouble finding a way to make this work as the method needed to refresh the page is in a different class than the settings flyout.  Is there a way to do this using events?

Comment: Post some code, that you have done. Whether it's working or not.

Comment: Check out Mvvm Light's Messenger system. It will allow your settings flyout to send a message directly to your Page. All your Page has to do is register to receive the message and pass in an Action to do upon receiving it (such as your Refresh logic).

Comment: @Xyroid That wouldn't serve any purpose. The problem was I didn't know what approach I should take, not how to correct something I already did.